# Enabling PCIE AER reporting

Tags: kernel, pcie

I'm running Ubuntu 16.10 desktop with Kernel 4.8.0-22-generic. I'm trying to enable PCI AER reporting.

`` /boot/config-`uname -r` `` shows

```
CONFIG_ACPI_APEI_PCIEAER=y
CONFIG_PCIAER=y
CONFIG_PCIEPORTBUS=y
```

so clearly AER reporting has been enabled. Yet in dmesg I see this:

```
acpi PNP0A08: _OSC: platform does not support [AER]
```

I have tried this on several systems with different SuperMicro motherboards and I see the same message.

Any idea what is going wrong and what can be done to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

No all motherboard has PCIe AER capable root complex. Also, I would check you don't have pci=noaer in your kernel boot argument.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `CONFIG_PCIAER=y` try `CONFIG_PCIEAER=y`.

Comment: Welcome to AU.  Could you provide more information on the reason why you think it will work?

Answer (score 0):

PCI AER is disabled by default in the BIOS of SuperMicro machines. To check if yours is as well, either load up BIOS and look under ACPI settings, or search "AER" in your motherboard's manual.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to ensure Linux is running in PCIe Native Mode, in order for it to take over PCIe services, such as hot plug, DPC, AER.  Many systems don't have the required features in the BIOS (ACPI 4.0+ & _OSC method) for the OS to automatically go into this mode.  You can force it on with 'pcie_ports=native' kernel parameter.